# Reversing Autocorrect, aka how to find the word that was supposed to be there

Tags: probability-or-statistics

When I receive messages from people using their smartphones I usually see typos and, worst, typos corrected by Autocorrect. Now, I receive messages in English, which is not my first language. I can easily understand what unfixed typos are supposed to mean (I just need to take a look at the keyboard), but Autocorrect-ed typos are an entirely different beast. They usually are totally different words, and the context doesn't help very much.
Is there a way in Mathematica to provide in input an English dictionary and an Autocorrect-ed word, and get as output all the words that, slightly mispelled, would lead to the Autocorrect-ed word?

Addendum: here's the sentence in which I'm 99% sure that "IMAP" is the result of autocorrection.

> It is memorial weekend so IMAP working extra long hour

Comment: If it isn't clear from context, how can one possibly guess how someone might have misspelled an unknown word to generate a correction? I strongly suspect that autocorrect is not an invertible function.

Comment: I guess you can use knowledge of nearby keys on the keyboard to narrow it down...but even so!

Comment: @OleksandrR. : the word of interest ("IMAP", yes, like the email protocol) doesn't make any sense in the specific sentence, but I have an hard time at finding what was meant instead. Autocorrect is invertible, not all the gibberish you type gets converted in real words, so there's a finite set of input sequences that lead to an AC-ed word.

Comment: @blochwave : "but even so!". Exactly! Human brain works better at finding faces in clouds rather than similar sequences on a keyboard leading to real words. Or, at least, my own brain works this way.

Comment: @Marco see if my suggestion helps if you add `IgnoreCase->True`

Comment: I edited the post so you can just copy the code and try it with "IMAP"

Comment: "It is memorial weekend so IMAP working extra long hour" - this could, for example, be "...so I'm working..." or "...so imagine working..." (as Marco points out...). Either is valid, so how do you overcome that problem?

Comment: By the same token, in this context, how can one tell that "working" isn't an autocorrected form of a misspelled "waking"? Basically, it seems to me that the only reliable solution to this problem is to ask your correspondents to send correct messages.

Comment: Come on, guys, the question isn't asking for magic. It clearly asks to "provide in input an English dictionary **and an Autocorrect-ed word**, and get as output **all the words** that, slightly mispelled, would lead to the Autocorrect-ed word" (emphasis mine). So lack of one-to-one-ness is not a problem, nor is it required to automatically detect Autocorrection.

Comment: @RahulNarain well, the fundamental problem here is ambiguity. You cannot realistically infer how someone might have misspelled something unknown with any certainty. If a "solution" produces a huge number of possibilities but can provide absolutely no confidence that any of them are correct, what use is that? If the question is just "produce a list of words that sound or are spelled similarly to a candidate word", that's something entirely different.

Comment: @Oleksandr: What I understand from the way the question is written (and Marco's recent comment on the answer below) is that the user will then look at the list of possible words and use their own judgement. It doesn't have to be a fully automatic deAutocorrectizer.

Comment: @RahulNarain well, if we have some context, then perhaps we can e.g. generate forwards and backwards Markov models of some corpus to find likely alternatives to the questioned word, and then choose as possible candidates the ones whose (mis)spellings, typos, and close phonological matches are similar to the suspect term. Without context, though, and without knowledge of how autocorrect works on the correspondent's device, I wouldn't like to try to infer anyone's intent. That [could lead to serious misunderstandings](http://www.cnet.com/uk/news/auto-corrected-text-leads-to-killing/).

Comment: Let me clarify my point, which was more about punctuation and common mis-spelling, that is, "I'm" and "Im" compared to IMAP. @Marco said he thought the word was "imagine", but from the sentence I myself would infer "I'm".

Comment: That would be a dictionary expansion/extension as talked about by @mfvonh in the answer below.

Comment: Am I missing something here? How about, e.g., `nearWords = Nearest[DictionaryLookup[__]];
nearWords["IMAP", 100]` - this returns "I'm" as one of the results, pretty sure that's the content of the example text.

Comment: @rasher The only potential drawback, as I understand it, is if you want to use a tailored distance function, which can make things quite slow when iterating over the whole dictionary.

Comment: But otherwise yes that is the simplest solution hah.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a pretty crude implementation but I think it shows the basic idea. You could do all sorts of things to tweak the pattern:

```
word="inert";
SortBy[DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[DictionaryLookup[#,IgnoreCase->True]& /@ 
  ReplaceList[StringSplit[word,""],{head___,_String,tail___} :> 
  StringJoin[head,"*",tail]]],StringLength]
```

> {inept,inert,inerts,insert,invert,inertia,inertly,inexact,inerrant,inertial,inexpert,inelegant,inertness,introvert,inefficient,inexpedient,inequivalent,ineradicable,ineradicably}

**EDIT**

Alright I'll explain a bit more. This problem does not have a general solution. The key issue is that autocorrection is *many to one*, so at best you can produce a set of candidates that could have been "corrected" to the word you received. Mathematica's DictionaryLookup function is useful but will not be enough here because it is limited to single words in "correct" English (or other language it supports). Language in an SMS is likely to be abbreviated, and in any case it is very likely to contain proper nouns that DictionaryLookup will not recognize. So a robust solution would need to supplement the built-in dictionary with other "words" that could be expected.

Many of the freely available corpora (collections of texts that can be used to establish statistical baselines when analyzing text data) are built on literary texts, which is not going to be of much help here unless your SMS conversations read like Jane Austen. (Again, one of the key things we need collect is proper nouns, which could be practically anything.) I have seen corpora that have, for example, scraped Wikipedia, which I imagine would be your best bet. There are also more specialized corpora, especially if you are willing to pay for one, and you can always assemble data yourself. All you really need is a list of words the user could have meant, and if possible it would be useful to have a set of weights for those words reflecting how likely they are to appear.

There are two things you have to "design". First, you need a method that takes the word you received and searches your dictionary (so, DictionaryLookup and your other data) for similar words. That means we need to define "similar". Second, you need a way to rank the matches. Coming up with a satisfactory definition of "similar" is possible, but accurately ranking those results is pretty much off the table because this is a function of unknowns. All autocorrection algorithms work the same way (they check what you typed against a dictionary) but we don't know anything about this particular dictionary (and it might include user-defined words) nor this particular algorithm (which may consider user-specific data when ranking suggestions), nor of course do we know what the user actually typed. This means that when it comes to ranking we just have to use our best guess.

Let me show you a better example. I'll define a "distance function" between two strings that does not penalize potential adjacent-key typos.

Here's a typical keyboard layout:

```
rows=Cases[Import["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY","XMLObject"],XMLElement["blockquote",_,c_]->c,\[Infinity]][[-1,2,3,{1,3,5,7}]]//ToLowerCase//StringReplace[#,RegularExpression["[^[:alnum:]]"]->""]&//StringSplit[#,""]&//Rest
```

> {{q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p},{a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l},{z,x,c,v,b,n,m}}

Now let's create tuples of adjacent keys. I don't know if this exact alignment is universal but the following was accurate on the several keyboards around my apartment:

```
positions=Position[rows,_String,\[Infinity]];
alts=Function[pos,
 Select[positions,
  Or[
   pos[[1]]==#[[1]]&&Abs[pos[[2]]-#[[2]]]<=1,
   pos[[1]]+1==#[[1]]&&-1<=#[[2]]-pos[[2]]<=0,
   pos[[1]]-1==#[[1]]&&0<=#[[2]]-pos[[2]]<=1
  ]&]]/@positions//Extract[rows,#]&/@#&;
```

The next step is to search for *all* possible candidates. I'm only using `DictionaryLookup`, and the patterns I've written could be made much better. The key thing they do is insert a bunch of wildcards and substitute each character with an `Alternatives` containing that character and adjacent ones (on the keyboard). To improve this you could, for example, make some assumptions about how many characters the user typed (varying by word length probably), and then (assuming the end of the word was supplied by autocorrect) not make the `Alternatives` substitutions toward the end of the string.

```
word="IMAP"//ToLowerCase//StringReplace[#," "->"*"]&;
candidates=Alternatives@@ReplaceList[
 StringReplace[word,
  MapThread[Rule,{Flatten[rows],Alternatives@@@alts}]],
 StringExpression[first_,head___,_Alternatives,tail___]:>
  StringExpression[first,head,"*",tail]]//DictionaryLookup;

candidates // Length
```

> 1137

That's a lot of candidates, so hopefully we can find a decent way to rank them. Again you have a ton of choices here, many involving the `SequenceAlignment` group of functions. We can use an option to specify how those functions define and handle matches/mismatches, so we will tell them to treat adjacent letters on the keyboard as if they were the same, and penalize everything else. This is an area you would want to tweak: certain typos are much more likely than others, and you may want other wildcard rules besides `{a_,b_}` (which is catching all pairs not recognized as adjacent keys).

```
similar=Append[#->1&/@(MapThread[Tuples[{##}]&,{List/@Flatten[rows],alts}]//Flatten[#,1]&//DeleteDuplicates),{a_,b_}->-1]
```

> {{q,q}->1,{q,w}->1,{q,a}->1,{w,q}->1,{w,w}->1,{w,e}->1,{w,a}->1,{w,s}->1,{e,w}->1,{e,e}->1,{e,r}->1,{e,s}->1,{e,d}->1,{r,e}->1,{r,r}->1,{r,t}->1,{r,d}->1,{r,f}->1,{t,r}->1,{t,t}->1,{t,y}->1,{t,f}->1,{t,g}->1,{y,t}->1,{y,y}->1,{y,u}->1,{y,g}->1,{y,h}->1,{u,y}->1,{u,u}->1,{u,i}->1,{u,h}->1,{u,j}->1,{i,u}->1,{i,i}->1,{i,o}->1,{i,j}->1,{i,k}->1,{o,i}->1,{o,o}->1,{o,p}->1,{o,k}->1,{o,l}->1,{p,o}->1,{p,p}->1,{p,l}->1,{a,q}->1,{a,w}->1,{a,a}->1,{a,s}->1,{a,z}->1,{s,w}->1,{s,e}->1,{s,a}->1,{s,s}->1,{s,d}->1,{s,z}->1,{s,x}->1,{d,e}->1,{d,r}->1,{d,s}->1,{d,d}->1,{d,f}->1,{d,x}->1,{d,c}->1,{f,r}->1,{f,t}->1,{f,d}->1,{f,f}->1,{f,g}->1,{f,c}->1,{f,v}->1,{g,t}->1,{g,y}->1,{g,f}->1,{g,g}->1,{g,h}->1,{g,v}->1,{g,b}->1,{h,y}->1,{h,u}->1,{h,g}->1,{h,h}->1,{h,j}->1,{h,b}->1,{h,n}->1,{j,u}->1,{j,i}->1,{j,h}->1,{j,j}->1,{j,k}->1,{j,n}->1,{j,m}->1,{k,i}->1,{k,o}->1,{k,j}->1,{k,k}->1,{k,l}->1,{k,m}->1,{l,o}->1,{l,p}->1,{l,k}->1,{l,l}->1,{z,a}->1,{z,s}->1,{z,z}->1,{z,x}->1,{x,s}->1,{x,d}->1,{x,z}->1,{x,x}->1,{x,c}->1,{c,d}->1,{c,f}->1,{c,x}->1,{c,c}->1,{c,v}->1,{v,f}->1,{v,g}->1,{v,c}->1,{v,v}->1,{v,b}->1,{b,g}->1,{b,h}->1,{b,v}->1,{b,b}->1,{b,n}->1,{n,h}->1,{n,j}->1,{n,b}->1,{n,n}->1,{n,m}->1,{m,j}->1,{m,k}->1,{m,n}->1,{m,m}->1,{a_,b_}->-1}

Now I'll define a distance function using those rules:

```
dist[w1_,w2_]:=
 StringLength[w1]/(
  SmithWatermanSimilarity[w1,w2,
   IgnoreCase->True,
   SimilarityRules->similar,
   GapPenalty->0]+.001 (*could be 0*));
```

I found some frequency data [here](http://invokeit.wordpress.com/frequency-word-lists/). I'll add a wildcard for unrecognized words and give them a frequency of 1, and then rescale the list to the range [0, 1].

```
freqData=Import["path...\\en-2012.zip",{"en.txt"}];
freqs=Append[
 Rule@@@MapAt[ToExpression,StringSplit[StringSplit[freqData,"\n"]],{All,-1}],
 _String->1];
freqs[[All,2]]=Rescale@freqs[[All,2]];
freqs=Dispatch[freqs];
```

Now I'll score the candidates using my distance function and the frequency data. This is the magic sauce: you've got to play around with with the different mechanisms you design to get this right.

```
scored=MapThread[
 {#1,Plus[#2,#3]}&,
 {candidates,dist[#,word]&/@candidates,
  -(candidates/.freqs)}]//SortBy[#,Last]&;
```

You could also make use of `WordData`. If you think it's a verb, let Mathematica know:

```
Select[scored,MemberQ[WordData[#[[1]],"PartsOfSpeech"],"Verb"]&]
```

> {{okay,1.29508},{image,1.66541},{unzip,1.6661},{okays,1.66611},{unsay,1.66611},{inset,1.66611},{inspire,1.74947},{inspect,1.74949},{unwound,1.74956},{insist,1.99882},{undo,1.9989},{images,1.99898},{insult,1.99898},{kidnap,1.99916}, ... }

This means the distance between "okay" and "IMAP", plus the "likelihood" of "okay", is 1.29508 (where lower is better). Recall the distance function treats adjacent keys as the same.

The most obvious improvements that could be made to this are expanding the dictionary and thinking more carefully about how the patterns and sequence alignments should work. In particular I think it would require some conditional logic based on word length.

**UPDATE**

Out of curiosity I ran this on "inert":

> {{jeer,0.999744},{inset,0.9998},{insert,1.1997},{insets,1.19976},{kneel,1.2495},{index,1.24963},{obey,1.33246},{observe,1.39947},{undergo,1.39968},{inserts,1.39971},{unstrap,1.39972},{unwrap,1.49961},{obsess,1.49961},{kneels,1.49962},{invert,1.49962},{unseat,1.49962},{unseal,1.49962},{indent,1.49962},{unreel,1.49963},{instruct,1.59963},{inserted,1.59966},{obstruct,1.59967},{observes,1.59967},{undercut,1.59968},...}

Comment: Isn't this more of an autocorrect than an inverse autocorrect? If the message writer attempted to type "snort" but wrote "inort" and this was corrected to "inert", the problem is to get from "inert" to "snort".

Comment: Thank you @mfvonh . Even if I'm still studying your code I already tried it and maybe it found the right word, "imagine". I updated the OP with the sentence of interest.

Comment: @SimonWoods Essentially they work the same way. I've added more detail in my edit, but both are just checking against a dictionary using wildcards and weights.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the extremely complete explanation.